# php_memcache.dll for php 5.2.2

Tags: windows, php-extension, php-5.2

I need php_memcache.dll for this php version: **5.2.2**

Now I've tried find it here http://museum.php.net/php5/
but in Pecl for php 5.2.2 there is **no such file**.

There are memcache .dll in later versions, but they don't work for me.

I have also tried:
" www.pureformsolutions.com/pureform.wordpress.com/2008/06/17/php_memcache.dll for PHP 5.2.* ", but still doesn't work.

Now do you know anywhere I can get the file for this version or can you help me to build in from source with Cygwin on Windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know this one? http://downloads.php.net/pierre/
Please, let me know.